# Nginx open_file_cache how to invalidate(purge) one file

Tags: nginx

For example, we have enabled open_file_cache in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=60s;
open_file_cache_valid    60s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   on;
```

Some file /my/file.jpg was changed, we know it on server-side. Example location block, hits this file:

```
location ~ (.+)\.[^\.][^\.][^\.]?[^\.]?[^\.]?[^\.]?$
{
    include /etc/nginx/upload.mime.types;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    root                               $hostdir;
    try_files                          $uri =404;
    error_page 404 /public/404.png;
}
```

How to clear it's cache server-side?

Answer (score 0):

You can add special argument recognition to a file request. If this argument is passed - you need to set the option `open_file_cache_valid 0s`. Example:

```
location ~ (.+)\.[^\.][^\.][^\.]?[^\.]?[^\.]?[^\.]?$
{
    include /etc/nginx/upload.mime.types;
    error_page 419 = @purgecache;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    if ($arg_purgecache) {
        #directly set "open_file_cache off;" here not works, don't know why
        return 419;
    }
    root                               $hostdir;
    try_files                          $uri =404;
    error_page 404 /public/404.png;
}

location @purgecache
{
    open_file_cache_valid 0s;
    root                               $hostdir;
    try_files                          $uri =404;
    error_page 404 /public/404.png;
}
```

On the backend side (for example PHP) - just add to url purgecache parameter. But value needs to randomize, to disable browser caching:

```
<img src="/my/file.jpg?purgecache=<?=rand(1000,1000000000)?>">
```

Or only server-side purge:

```
file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/my/file.jpg?purgecache=".rand(1000,1000000000));
```